# How to insert N elements to a Document in Mongo using Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am trying the past 3 days to do it and could not succeed yet. I have the following code, that adds a Book do a `Books` colection on a MongoDB. The App is build with meteor:

```
    //save authors book information
    //as a book can have N authors, this loop get all input fields with authors

    var authors = [];
    $('.author-field').each(function(){
        authors.push[{
            'author': $(this).val()
        }]
    });

    //save static book information
    var book = {
        title: $(e.target).find('[name=add-title]').val(),
        (...)
        language: $(e.target).find('[name=add-language]').val(),
        authors: authors //add all authors here
    }

    Meteor.call('bookInsert', book, authors, areas, function(error, result) {
        if(error)
            return throwError(error.reason);
        Router.go('/');
    });
```

And I always get an error. Now I am getting this:

`errorClass {message: "Match error: Unknown key in field authors", path: "authors", sanitizedError: errorClass, errorType: "Match.Error", stack: (...)…}`

Other times, with few changes, I has getting: `was expecting an object and got an array` or something like that.
What am I doing wrong here?

-- Update --

The code that actually add to db is this one:

```
    //meteor methods
Meteor.methods({
  bookInsert: function(postAttributes, authors, areas) {
    check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(postAttributes, {
        title: String,
        (...)
        language: String,
        authors: Object
    });
    var user = Meteor.user();
    //_.extend comes from Underscore library
    var book = _.extend(postAttributes, { 
        userId: user._id,
        author: user.username,
        submitted: new Date()
    });
    var bookId = Books.insert(book);


    return {
        _id: bookId
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Please add the code for the `bookInsert` method.

Comment: Sorry, @DavidWeldon, added here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a couple of things that you can do.

First, to get the author data into your array you need to change the brackets of the `push` function from `[` to `(`:

```
var authors = [];
$('.author-field').each(function(){
    authors.push({
        'author': $(this).val()
    })
});
```

`console.log( authors )` afterwards to confirm that it worked.

Second, you need to check against an array of objects as @EduardoC.K.Ferreira suggested. so your check function should look like this

```
check(postAttributes, {
    title: String,
    (...)
    language: String,
    authors: [Object]
});
```

that should get it going. however, there are two more things i noticed:

1. why do you pass three arguments in your call
   `Meteor.call('bookInsert', book, authors, areas, ...` but you don't
   use them. Plus, the authors array is contained within the book
   object, so why pass it again separately?
2. i assume you want to confirm that a user is logged in here: `check(Meteor.userId(), String);`. you should use the the `this.userId` object in method calls (see [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_userId)) and check that it is not `null`, i.e. user is logged in

like so:

```
if (! this.userId)
  throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You must be logged in!");
```

Finally, be sure that `user.username` exists before you use it. hope that helps.

Comment: This was perfect, @tomsp, thanks! The areas argument is for another array of information that was also not working, but it behave the same as authors, so solving one would solve the other. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've specified the authors field check incorrectly, you have it matching an object where it looks like it should be an Array.

Try changing the following in your method to see if you're able to save :

```
check(postAttributes, {
    title: String,
    (...)
    language: String,
    authors: Any
});
```

If I understand the documentation correctly, it looks like you'll need to check for an array of objects with something like `[Object]`.

Comment: hmm, no, @pushplaybang, it did not work. Got a `Any is not defined`.

Comment: that is because the syntax is ```check( authors: Match.Any )``` see [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/matchpatterns). But you should check against an array of objects as @EduardoC.K.Ferreira suggested. so do ```check(authors: [Object]) ```.

Comment: It almost work, @tomsp, the error is not showing up anymore, but if I ask to see the colection on mongo, authors is empty like this `"authors": [ ]`, even if Ihave added 5 or 6 entries. Is the loop correct? With that push and etc?

Comment: did you ```console.log( authors )``` after the loop to see if all the authors are actually in the array?

Comment: Hmm, it is also empty on `console.log( authors )` actually... if I `console.log($(this).val());` inside the loop then it returns each field value, but it is not pushing to the array. So the problem is up there, on the push. Do you know what is wrong, @tomsp?